# Show completion list when qlineEdit textChanged

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I can use the following command to show an auto completion list view if I have a predefined list

```
wordList =["alpha", "omega", "omicron", "zeta"]
completer = QCompleter(wordList)
ineEdit.setCompleter(completer)
```

[image]

I need a different case:, Type something in `lineEdit`, when textChanged it connect to a function `def searchAction:` via `lineEdit.textChanged.connect(searchAction)`. Inside `def searchAction:` i have an sql query which updates a list (say `data_list`) for every string I type in the `lineEdit` . If set `wordList` as `data_list` it does not do anything. My question how can I show the `data_list` as a autocompletion something like in the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to create lists since QCompleter supports models so you can filter using QSqlQueryModel as shown below:

```py
import os
import sys
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QCompleter, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQuery, QSqlQueryModel

CURRENT_DIRECTORY = Path(__file__).resolve().parent


def create_connection(path):
    db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
    db.setDatabaseName(path)
    if not db.open():
        print(db.lastError().text())
        return False
    return True


class SqlQueryCompleter(QCompleter):
    def __init__(self, sql_model=None, parent=None):
        super().__init__(sql_model, parent)
        if sql_model is None:
            sql_model = QSqlQueryModel(self)
        elif not isinstance(sql_model, QSqlQueryModel):
            raise ValueError(f"The {sql_model} must be an instance of QSqlQueryModel")
        self.setModel(sql_model)
        self.setCompletionMode(QCompleter.UnfilteredPopupCompletion)

    def splitPath(self, path):
        if isinstance(self.model(), QSqlQueryModel):
            self.model().setQuery(self.query(path))
        return super().splitPath(path)

    def query(self, path):
        query = QSqlQuery("SELECT bar FROM 'foo' WHERE bar LIKE ?")
        query.addBindValue(f"%{path}%")
        if not query.exec_():
            print(query.lastError().text())
        return query


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    filename = os.fspath(CURRENT_DIRECTORY / "database.db")

    if not create_connection(filename):
        sys.exit(-1)

    line_edit = QLineEdit()
    line_edit.show()

    completer = SqlQueryCompleter()
    line_edit.setCompleter(completer)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed code, I am wondering from where `def splitPath` is being called

Comment: @sadath Why do you think there is a setCompleter method? Well, because QLineEdit invokes the necessary methods to do the search and then internally splitPath is invoked. You should also know that when you pass your string list this the end is stored in a model as well. Your question can also be applied: how do you call the method that converts what I type on the keyboard to letters in the QLineEdit?

Comment: I had gone through Qt documentation and found the use of splitPath. Initially I was calling the QSqlQuery by means of strings extracted from `lineEdit.textChanged`. Your code works for me thank you .